# Pyspark : is there any way to use Unix exported variables in python code

Tags: python, unix, pyspark

I am looking for a solution to get Unix exported variables in pyspark code when I am running it on cluster mode.
I got a solution using os.getenv but this is not working in cluster mode for me. In local mode it is working fine.

Is there any other way to replaces complete set of variables in one go. Passing n number of arguments and reading them is a bit overhead.

Answer (score 0):

For a cluster mode you should use spark configuration named `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.XXX` to pass variables to the driver. You can find more information in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html).

But, I woudn't say environment variables are the best way to deal with parameters. Did you head about `optparse` library? It is shipped with all python distributions (2.X and 3.X) and allows you to parse parameters in quite easy way, like:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-i", "--input-file", default="hdfs:///some/input/file.csv")
parser.add_option("-o", "--output-dir", default= "hdfs:///tmp/output")
parser.add_option("-l", "--log-level", default='INFO')

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Look like, It will read the file from HDFS. I created one dictionary by reading the HDFS file and I was able to use it. But here, I was more interested in knowing, if there is any way to pass the file directly from edge node to pass the parameters. For example, I want to pass my schema name, table name and 15-20 more variables in the script. If you will pass and collect by sys.argv, it will work but it is like I will have to take care of location and collection.

Comment: Or you can take my question this way, Is there any way to read local edge node file in cluster mode. I tried using file:/// but it did not work.

Comment: You can tell `spark-submit` to deploy a file with your application using `--files` parameter. Then you can use it like a normal, local file (with `open('filename')`)